# Обработка запросов с Яндекс кассы Django

Tags: python, json, django, яндекс-касса

О великие, нужна Ваша помощь. Уже несколько дней бьюсь в истерике, пытаясь сделать получение уведомлений от Яндекс Кассы.

Есть вот такие вьюха получения уведомлений:

```
class YandexNotifications(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        event_json = json.loads(request.body)
        value = int(event_json["object"]["description"])
        order = Order.published.get(id=value)
        order.paid = True
        order.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Вот такие урлы:

```
app_name = 'payment'

urlpatterns = [
    path('notifications/', YandexNotifications.as_view(), name='notifications'),
    path('canceled/', views.payment_canceled, name='canceled'),
    path('process/<int:order_id>/', views.payment_process, name='process'),
]
```

Если отсылаю запрос с https://reqbin.com/, то всё ок. Если пытаюсь тестировать через Яндекс, то ничего не происходит. логирования в лк яндекс на нотификации нет, поддержки от них также не очень дождешься(кидаются на доку https://kassa.yandex.ru/developers/using-api/webhooks)

Comment: А в настройках Яндекс Кассы для WebHooks указан ли корректный URL с доменом или статическим IP, на котором слушает этот код?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот такой урл c https: https://mrpit.online/payment/notifications

Comment: А в логах NginX или Джанго не видно обращений по этому юрлу с Кассы? И что значит `Если отсылаю запрос с https://reqbin.com/, то всё ок` – куда, откуда, какой запрос и зачем? ВебХуки ведь не про отправку своих запросов, а получение запросов с интересуемой инфой от нужного сервиса.

Comment: с кассы прилетает JSON, который указан в документации https://kassa.yandex.ru/developers/using-api/webhooks. https://reqbin.com/ я имитирую POST запрос на свой хост и вьюха отрабатывает всё как надо (ловлю вебхуку) на бою с яндексом не работает. Логи NginX не знаю как получить..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение банально:
В кабинете Яндекс кассы не хватало слэша в конце ссылки
https://mrpit.online/payment/notifications/

Comment: И ещё бывает request.body django отдает пустым и нужно принимать request.data

Answer (score 0):

по логам Nginx сайт возвращает 500 ошибку, когда запрос идёт с Яндекса.
когда я посылаю абсолютно такой же запрос с https://mrpit.online/payment/notifications (restframework), то 200 респонс 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]